# React BrowserRouter works when navigating on localhost. Refreshing a not-home-page when deployed throws 404 not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My code is using React-router-dom. It works on gh-pages with all navigation within the page. However, accessing by adding /blog to the url or refreshing the /blog page returns 404 not found. The app is structured like this:

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <header className="App-header" width="100%" >
          <BrowserRouter basename="/">
            <Switch>
            <Route component={Main} exact path="/" /> 
            <Route component={Blog} exact path="/blog" /> 
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Blog.js:

```
function Blog() {
  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <header className="App-header" width="100%" >
        <div id="home" width="100%">
          <BrowserRouter id="blog">
              
              <div>
                <Route component={AllPosts} exact path="/blog/"  />
                <Route component={OnePost} exact path="/blog/:slug" />
              </div>
              
          </BrowserRouter>

          <SidebarIfBrowser />

        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Blog;
```

Do I miss something essential?

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: react-router v5

Comment: awesome I think my new answer would resolve this issue for you then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks to be about how you are using nested routes.

First in `App.js` remove the exact because you don't want it to be exact

```js
// App.js
<Switch>
    <Route component={Main} exact path="/" /> 
    <Route component={Blog} path="/blog" /> 
</Switch>
```

Now in your `Blog.js` there are a few edits you need to make. First is to replace your `BrowserRouter` with `Switch`. You only want to have 1 `BrowserRouter` in your entire app and it should be in the high level which is what you have in your `App.js`.
Then you want to change the `paths` in your Routes. You dont need to include `/blog/` in them since they are nested routes within the `/blog` route from your `App.js` Technically what you have before would of been `/blog/blog`

```js
// Blog.js
function Blog() {
  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <header className="App-header" width="100%" >
        <div id="home" width="100%">
          <Switch>
              <div>
                <Route component={AllPosts} exact path="/"  />
                <Route component={OnePost} exact path="/:slug" />
              </div>
          </Switch>

          <SidebarIfBrowser />

        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Blog;
```

note this only works for react-router v5 and if you are using v6 then there are some other changes you would need

Comment: This was indeed correct. Additionally, Olivier Boisse's answer was necessary for making it work on github pages. I swapped BrowserRouter for HashRouter, which was an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem when deploying a SPA to github pages. To make the client side routing work, every request must be redirected to the `index.html` and this behavior is not implemented by github pages.

This is explained in the [create react app documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing). It seems that you have two solutions :

1. switch from using HTML5 history API to routing with hashes
2. follow this [guide](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages). You must add a custom `404.html` page to your project and add a custom script tag to your `index.html` page. I already used this solution, it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're making a GET request on the server for a non existing route. You can fix this by following the steps bellow:

**1. Point the home page in your package.json**

```
 {
    ...
    "homepage": ".",
    ...
}
```

**2. Create a .htaccess file and place it in the root directory of your app**

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
        
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**NOTE:** This is valid only when you deploy your React app. On development you can access any route by only using React Router.